# Dragging in HTML customization

Tags: javascript, html

In a program I am creating, I need to have dragging. I figured out this part through [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) but I can't seem to figure out how to customize it... What I'm trying to achieve is dragging but no ghost effect, and making it so the original image is hidden so it looks like it is only one image. Another thing I'm trying to do is get rid of the symbols. I'm clueless as to how to get rid of the symbols, and I can't manage to change the opacity of the ghost image... I've looked at a few other answers but I can't seem to get it to work.
[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Officer1/pLkcfm5L/)

```
 #pointer1{pointer-events:none} //This prevents selecting of the drag. Not what I wanted
 #pointer1{/*How to change the ghost?*/}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tested in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sure thing! I edited the post so you can see what I've tried...

Comment: Ohn, you're using the native drag function. That's tricky. The only way I've found to do that (remove the ghost effect) it's creating my own javascript drag behavior or you can use a [plugin](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/). So you have more 'power' to do what you want.

Comment: I had an ready answer for your recent post. *but you deleted it'

Comment: Oh, the recent post was resolved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery for this. It will let you set options for the things you're looking for. 
[jQuery UI Drag Documentstion](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this "JQuery Documentstion"